# Already used port in running open project (closed)

Tags: openproject

I have installed open project on a vmware, Ubuntu 20.04

this is my configuration file:

```
openproject/edition default
postgres/autoinstall install
postgres/db_host 127.0.0.1
postgres/db_port 45432
postgres/db_name ***********
postgres/db_username ***********
postgres/db_password ***************************
server/autoinstall install
server/hostname localhost
server/server_path_prefix /donation
server/ssl no
repositories/api-key *****************
repositories/svn-install install
repositories/svn-path /var/db/openproject/svn
repositories/apache-wrapper-token *********************
repositories/git-install skip
memcached/autoinstall install
openproject/admin_email ****************

postgres/addon_version v1
server/variant apache2
```

and it was config correctly.

when I ran the "openproject run web" command, I faced with following error:

```
opt/openproject/config/constants/settings/definition.rb:1298:in `find_env_var_override': Using unprefixed environment variables is deprecated. Please use OPENPROJECT_RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT instead of RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT (StructuredWarnings::StandardWarning)
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 7.0.6 application starting in production 
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
[6581] Puma starting in cluster mode...
[6581] * Puma version: 6.3.0 (ruby 3.2.1-p31) ("Mugi No Toki Itaru")
[6581] *  Min threads: 4
[6581] *  Max threads: 16
[6581] *  Environment: production
[6581] *   Master PID: 6581
[6581] *      Workers: 2
[6581] *     Restarts: (✔) hot (✖) phased
[6581] * Preloading application
Exiting
/opt/openproject/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/puma-6.3.0/lib/puma/binder.rb:334:in `initialize': Address already in use - bind(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 6000 (Errno::EADDRINUSE)
```

and this is list of my listening ports:

```
ruby      6403     openproject    7u  IPv4 146687      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:6000 (LISTEN)
ruby      6427     openproject    7u  IPv4 146687      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:6000 (LISTEN)
ruby      6430     openproject    7u  IPv4 146687      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:6000 (LISTEN)
```

so what is my problem?

Comment: Could it be as simple as OpenProject already running? Have you tried accessing the application with a browser?

Comment: yes, you are right. actually, I have to access the open project with a browser and 127.0.1.1 Ip and instead of that, I used 127.0.0.1 IP.